# How to put link around an Html::submitButton in yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

how to put link on an Html::submitButton in yii2.
I am creating an application and want a logout button under the login form which when gets clicked(only if the user is still logged in), will take the user to the logout action.

I am using login button like this:

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just create link with `Html::a()`?

Comment: Thanks for replying yupik. But can you tell me how to do that. I am a beginner in yii2.

Comment: Being a beginner does not justify lazynes. Read the [really good documentation about this.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#hyperlinks)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

for logout use anchor instead of submit button.
try the following code :

```
Html::a('logout','site/logout',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','data-method'=>'POST']);
```